# Coffeescript dynamic hash key

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, babeljs

I want create grunt task for babel, what i need:

```
babel:
  one:
    files:
      "dist/somefile-1.0.js": "dist/somefile-1.0.js"
```

If I use string without variable inside, it's works.

I have global variable with version, what I tried to do:

```
version = "somefile-1.0"

babel:
  one:
    files:
      "dist/#{version}.js": "dist/#{version}.js"
```

In this case I've got this error: *Parse error on line 88: Unexpected '{'*

The second attempt:

```
patchV = {}
patchV["dist/#{version}.js"] = "dist/#{version}.js"

babel:
  one:
    files:
      patchV
```

In this case I didn't get the error, but nothing happened.

Use CoffeeScript 1.9.1.

Comment: Seems to work fine http://coffeescript.org/#try:babel%3A%0A%20%20one%3A%0A%20%20%20%20files%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dist%2F%23%7Bversion%7D.js%22%3A%20%22dist%2F%23%7Bversion%7D.js%22

Comment: I think so too, but if I use string without variable it's working. In another case, no.

Comment: What is that object assigned to? `babel:` is not a way to define a variable, did you mean `babel=`

Comment: It's name for grunt task https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#grunt

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same way you'd use in plain Javascript:

```
babel =
  one:
    files: {}

babel.one.files["dist/#{version}.js"] = "dist/#{version}.js"
```

Yes, it's slightly repetitive, but it's the most idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: `Loading "Gruntfile.coffee" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: babel is not defined`

Comment: Indeed, because you did not actually assign the object you were creating to any variable! Fixed this now in my sample. You might want to assign the variable to some other name yourself.

Comment: Got `>> No "babel" targets found.
Warning: Task "babel" failed. Use --force to continue.`

Comment: Give more context. I'm not familiar with grunt and its required syntax in particular. Does that means your original code compiles to `return { babel : ... }`? Or is there more surrounding code like `tasks = babel : ...`?

Comment: I think return { babel : ... }. Without CoffeeScript it looks like this https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#grunt